Uniswapv3 fetch tick with negative index is always empty
While fetching ticks, I noticed that I always get empty results for negative ticks (ticks with negative index). I must be missing something or be misunderstanding the way ticks work, as I cannot imagine the Uniswap team has missed this.
I use ticks for price calculation. So for the following pool, which has a positive tick index as the current tick, I get the following result:

Notice that I rounded the tick index to the tick spacing. When I do the same for a pool with a negative tick index, I always seem to get empty results:

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your feedback!

I was under the assumption that all ticks that are divisible by the tickSpacing are initialized, but turns out that they're not. UniswapV3 stores which ticks are initialized in something that's called a "Tick Bitmap Index" (see https://uniswapv3book.com/milestone_2/tick-bitmap-index.html for more info).
My solution would thus be to find the next initialized tick using this index (and not just the next initializable tick, which is not necessarily initialized with liquidity).
